# SurfaceControl alternative for screenshots

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm using this API of SurfaceControl to capture a screenshot:

```
public static Bitmap screenshot(int width, int height, int minLayer, int maxLayer) {
    // TODO: should take the display as a parameter
    IBinder displayToken = SurfaceControl.getBuiltInDisplay(
            SurfaceControl.BUILT_IN_DISPLAY_ID_MAIN);
    return nativeScreenshot(displayToken, width, height, minLayer, maxLayer, false);
}
```

The bitmap is returned fine however this process, as stated in the description (

```
 * CAVEAT: Versions of screenshot that return a {@link Bitmap} can
 * be extremely slow; avoid use unless absolutely necessary; prefer
 * the versions that use a {@link Surface} instead, such as
 * {@link SurfaceControl#screenshot(IBinder, Surface)}.
```

) make the phone stutter for 1/2 seconds.

The purpose is to develop a service that takes the screenshot so I can't use the suggested method with Surface (what should I pass to service)?

Since i'm working inside the framework I got access also to hidden API, any suggestion? thanks